# Why are some react-chartjs-2 options being ignored?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I have this simple line chart that I am trying to change the gridlines from their default gray, however the options object appears to be selectively working. Maybe I am missing something basic but I have been fiddling with it for hours and cannot get it to work, any help is appreciated! I am using "react-chartjs-2".

Below is my render() method where I pass the data and options.

```
render() {
        const data = {
            labels: this.state.realTimes,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Price",
                    data: this.state.Prices,
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255)"
                }
            ]
        };

        const options = {
            scales: {
                yAxis: {
                    beginAtZero: true, //this works

                    gridLines: {
                        color: "rgba(171,171,171,1)", //this doesn't
                        lineWidth: 0.5
                      }
                }
            }
        };
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.loading ? (
                    this.loading()
                ) : (
                    <Line  data={data} options={options} width={600} height={160}  />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `scales.yAxis.gridLines` to `scales.yAxis.grid` and it will work.

> see [Grid Line Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration) from Chart.js documentation or the [Grid Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/grid.html#grid-configuration) samples page.

Please take a look at below runnable JavaScript code and see how it works.

Please take a look at

```js
new Chart('line-chart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      tension: 0.2
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxis: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        grid: {
          color: 'rgb(0 ,0 ,255)',
          lineWidth: 0.5
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.1.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="line-chart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

React chart.js is not up to date with chart.js so you can't use v3. Please use the v2 syntax since that is what react-chartjs uses.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration

If you change `yAxes: {gridLines: {color: 'red'}}` to `yAxes: [{gridLines: { color: 'red'}}]` it should work as intended